# PHP 5.4 - CodeIgniter - PCRE library issue workaround in shared-hosting

Tags: php, cpanel, pcre, shared-hosting

I'm going to move codeigniter project from my computer to a public server (virtual private server where it has Cpanel installed in it).

In the public server I got the error :

```
Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown option bit(s) set at offset 0
```

You can check [here](http://www.sweet668.com/CI_auth_example/). 
After checking some other related questions, I can see that its because of the PCRE library used by the virtual private server is too old or it has no utf-8 support in it. 
The PCRE used version is 7.8. 
To see the phpinfo of my virtual server click [phpinfo here](http://www.sweet668.com/phpinfo.php).

Now, I know I CAN solve this by rebuilding pcre, php, etc. But my boss insist to use this registered virtual server, which only give me limited permissions. Only CPANEL account and FTP to upload/remove files

So the question is : 
- Is CodeIgniter MUST has this PCRE enabled to run ? 
- Is there any other workaround to make it run in the server ?

I already contacted the support, and they said, their CPanel ONLY support PCRE version 7.8 for the current moment. I'm confused, what this has to do with Cpanel ? Aren't it is just supposed to rebuild the PCRE library and let php config direct to it ? I mean Cpanel only GUI right ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you edit the `/system/core/Utf8.php` file.

On line 44 put an `@` in front of `preg_match`.

This should at least suppress the error message and allow the script to continue.

Original:

```
    function __construct()
    {
        log_message('debug', "Utf8 Class Initialized");

        global $CFG;

        if (
            preg_match('/./u', 'é') === 1                   // PCRE must support UTF-8
```

Modified:

```
    function __construct()
    {
        log_message('debug', "Utf8 Class Initialized");

        global $CFG;

        if (
            @preg_match('/./u', 'é') === 1                  // PCRE must support UTF-8
```

Comment: Yes I got the point. But I'm really curious, will it generate other problem ? Does Codeigniter really need this PCRE library ? I'm no CodeIgniter expert...

Comment: As far as I can tell no, "it shouldn't"™. It will allow the script to progress and define it's utf support variables. Worth a try at least.

Comment: And starting off a comment with "Yes I got the point" when someone has taken the time to help you out isn't really the best approach :P

Comment: I always thought ppl like when I said 'I got the point'.lol. Thanks very much for your feedback and time. I'll try your answer.

Comment: Hi Dale. I've tested it and kind of working without any error. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Got any explanation why CI do this check ? I also encounter escapeshellarg warning, but again use 'surpress warning' solution. Hope everything goes fine..

Comment: Judging from that file it looks as though it's used to check if the current environment supports utf-8 characters, which is then later used to define utf support, why they didn't suppress the error is beyond me. Searching google I managed to find a merged pull request where some bright spark made the adjustment, though it looks like it hasn't made it into the official release just yet.